# Cakephp 1.3 Set::extract using the OR XPATH operator

Tags: operators, cakephp-1.3

I would like to use Set::extract to pull back something like this.

```
Set::extract('/User[region_id=1 or email_region_id=1]', $users);
```

I could probably do this with multiple queries but I am not sure if this would be faster. It would definitely be easier given the current setup.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look possible at the moment.